# Chances of winning your money back on a double or nothing machine?

Tags: probability, games

A double or nothing machine is where you place in one token, and on your next turn you either double your token or lose it with a probability of *p*, you can then repeat this until your final bet is 64 tokens.

At what *p* is the player losing to the machine? What are the chances of winning your money back?

Answer (score 0):

Hint (as you have not demonstrated efforts to solve the problem):

You have 7 plays to double your money for an assumed constant probability of winning ${p}$.

So, you want a distribution that addresses the number of trials to the first success.

The distribution in question is the [Geometric Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) law.